# Musical and combinatorial proof

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers, music-theory

> How many distinct rhythms can a musical measure have?

Obviously the answer is not "$\infty$", so to answer this question we set a minimum rhythm  $\frac{1}{4}$. We will consider both notes and rests and **not** consider irregular groups like triplets and others. So we'll consider notes and rests as $\frac{1}{4 }$, $\frac{2}{4}$, $\frac{3}{4 }$ ...
As regards musical measure we'll consider $\frac{L}{4}$ where $L$ is the length of measure and consider only $L>0$.
Then calculate the number of combinations of rhythms in a measure:

[image]
[image]

So the sequence found is: $1,2,5,13,34,...$ and this is a possible relation with Fibonacci's bisection:
$$ F(0)=1 $$
$$ F(1)=2 $$
$$F(L)= 3 \cdot F(L-1) - F(L-2); \quad L>1$$
How is it possible to proof that this recurrence relation is valid for each $L>1$?

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**
Sorry i have forgotten to write that we consider rhythms from the acoustic view point, so we consider for example that two rests of $\frac{1}{4}$ acoustically equal to a rest of $\frac{2}{4}$ and so we will consider only the rest of $\frac{2}{4}$.

Furthermore rhythms of arbitrary duration are allowed, for example we can have a note of $\frac{5}{4}$ with a invented symbol.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be L mod 4 * 34 + the relevant remaining L=1,2,3

Comment: @ZirconCode sorry but i have to proof that recurrence relation

Comment: Do you consider two $\frac 12$ rests to be the same rythm than one whole rest ? Theorically they're not the same rythm but to the ears they are.

Comment: Why can't $L=3$ have three rests?  Would that be half/quarter or quarter/half?  In $L=4$ I also don't see a quarter followed by three beats of rest or three beats of rest followed by a quarter.  I think your counts are off.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes sorry i have forgotten to write that we consider rhythms from the acoustic view point, so we consider for example that two rests of 1/4 acoustically equal to a rest of 2/4 and so we will consider only the rest of 2/4. I edit the text of question now.

Comment: @krirkrirk  yes sorry i have forgotten to write that we consider rhythms from the acoustic view point.

Comment: Are notes of five or more beats allowed or are whole notes the longest?

Comment: @RossMillikan yes are allowed, we can have a note of 5/4 with a invented symbol. I have update the text with this detail. Thank you

Comment: You don't need to invent a symbol; just use ties...

Comment: @Micah yes but maybe it could be confusing, because it must be counted once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three cases:

- A rhythm ends with something which lasts longer than a quarter note. There are $F(n-1)$ of these: we can get each of them by taking an arbitrary rhythm of length $n-1$ and lengthening the last symbol by one beat.
- A rhythm ends with a quarter note. Then anything can come before the quarter note, so there are also $F(n-1)$ of these.
- A rhythm ends with a quarter rest. Then the next-to-last symbol must continue with a note and not a rest (as we are not allowed to have two uncombined adjacent rests). The number of rhythms of length $n-1$ which end with a rest is $F(n-2)$, as any one of them can be obtained by performing a rhythm of length $n-2$ and then resting for a quarter-beat. So there are $F(n-1)-F(n-2)$ rhythms of length $n-1$ which do not end in a rest.

This gives the order 2 recurrence relation
$$
F(n)=3F(n-1)-F(n-2)
$$
as you conjectured.

---

Another way to split things up that may be easier to think about:

- We might end with a rest of any length. In this case we can perform an arbitrary rhythm of length $n-1$ and then rest for a beat. So there are $F(n-1)$ possibilities.
- We might end with a quarter note. Again in this case we can perform an arbitrary rhythm of length $n-1$ and then a quarter note, so there are $F(n-1)$ possibilities.
- Finally, we might end with a longer note (not a rest). Then we can shorten this note by $1$ beat, to get an arbitrary rhythm of length $n-1$ that ends with a note. As in the first bullet point, there are $F(n-2)$ rhythms of length $n-1$ that end with a rest, so there are $F(n-1)-F(n-2)$ rhythms of length $n-1$ that end with a note.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes notes of arbitrary duration are allowed

Comment: @RossMillikan A seven beat note is just $7$ linked quarter notes which is clearly OK if $L>0$ has no maximum

Comment: Yes.  Well done.

Comment: @Micah Sorry three questions:
1. when you say "A rhythm starts" you mean "A measure starts"?
2. in the second point, when you say "the rest of it is arbitrary" you mean "what follows is arbitrary"?
3. in the third point, the measure can starts with rest of 2/4 or higher. doesn't it?

Thank you

Comment: 1-2. Yes, if you prefer. 3. If it starts with a rest of at least 2 beats, you combine them in the notation — but you can get it in a unique way by just resting for one extra beat before you start. It's probably easier to think about it in terms of the performance than in terms of the notation...

Comment: ok sorry i don't understand for example in the second point, if we take for example the measure with L=3 the number of these that start with a quarter note is 5 as you can see in the first image. So F(L-1)=F(2)=2 (in the fibonacci's sequence) and not 5. Is it correct?

Comment: If $L=3$, there are $5$ things that start with a quarter note, which is $F(3-1)$. I don't see what your confusion is...

Comment: Note that your $F(n)$ is the $2n$th Fibonacci number (which can be easily proved by induction once you have the recurrence relation).

Comment: yes, you're right. thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74044/discussion-between-juan-menashsheh-and-micah).

Comment: The first bullet point is about rhythms of length $n$; there are $F(n-1)$ rhythms of length $n$ that end in a rest. But for the third bullet point, we need to count rhythms of length $n-1$ that end in a rest, so there are $F(n-2)$ of them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different proof, which makes the connection to the Fibonacci numbers explicit as well as using some basic musical concepts. If people have trouble with unicode musical notes, let me know and I'll try to replace them with images, but they have fairly low code points, so hopefully it'll be okay as is. (Rests seem to be more poorly supported, so I'm using images for the examples at the end which involve them.)

The standard combinatorial interpretation of the Fibonacci numbers is that $f_k$ (suitably indexed) counts the number of ways of tiling a path of length $n$ with tiles of length either $1$ or $2$. In musical terms, $f_k$ counts the number of possible rhythms which are $k$ eighth-notes long, using only eighth notes and quarter notes (and no rests). If we let the quarter note have the beat and consider sequences which are $n$ beats long, it follows that there are $f_{2n}$ such sequences — the same number as there are of the types of rhythm you are trying to count.

Given this observation, it's very natural to look for a bijection between these two types of rhythm. And in fact we can find one.

Any sequence of quarter and eighth notes can be divided into:

- **Syncopated sections**: These consist of an eighth note that falls on the quarter-note beat (i.e., is preceded by an even number of eighth notes), followed by some number of quarter notes, followed by an offbeat eighth note (e.g., ♪♩♩♩♪).
- **Unsyncopated sections**: These consist of some number of quarter notes, all of which fall on the quarter-note beat (♩♩♩♩♩$\dots$).

Each of these sections takes up an integer number of quarter-note beats. Note that it is convenient for our purposes to regard a pair of adjacent eighth notes on the beat (♫) as a very short syncopated section, even though in musical terms it would not be considered syncopated.

Note that it is possible for one syncopated section to follow another (e.g., ♪♩♩♪♪♩♩♩♪). But if you concatenate two unsyncopated sections, you just get a single longer unsyncopated section (e.g., ♩♩ + ♩♩♩ = ♩♩♩♩♩). This is exactly analogous to the unrestricted rhythms in the question! In that case, you can play two notes in sequence, but if you "play" two rests in sequence, you just get a longer rest.

So our bijection will work as follows: given a sequence of eighth notes and quarter notes, we replace each syncopated section with a single note of the same length, and each unsyncopated section by a rest of the same length. Going in the other direction, if we have a sequence of notes and rests, all of which are some integer number of quarter-notes long, replace each note with a syncopated section of the same length, and each rest with an unsyncopated section of each length. These are clearly well-defined and inverse to each other, which completes the proof.

For concreteness, here are the $n=2$ examples of this bijection (quarter notes and eighth notes in the first measure of each line, longer notes and rests in the second measure):

[image: 4 eighth-notes = 2 quarter-notes]

[image: quarter + 2 eighths = rest + quarter]

[image: 2 eighths + quarter = quarter + rest]

[image: eighth + quarter + eighth = half]

[image: 2 quarters = half rest]

and a longer example:

[image: OMG 10 BEATS]